# Unable to take pull master branch on server

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm trying to take pull of my master branch that is denoted by branch name in below  command. when I run git pull origin branch name I 'm getting following message:

```
[------ server path]$ git pull origin branchname
error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.
[------ server path]$ git status
On branch branchname
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branchname' by 31 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        public/images/report.pdf
        public/img/Format.pdf
        public/img/attachment/01622024994.jpeg
        public/img/attachment/01622025119.jpeg
        public/img/attachment/01622038067.png
        public/img/attachment/01622039029.jpeg
        public/uploads/
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: The solution is there. You can't pull with a merge in progress. Did you do as it says and commit the changes?

Answer (score 1):

The message states that there is a pending merge, so you should isse the command `git merge --continue`, then retry with `git pull origin {{branchname}}`.

Is that your case?

Comment: should i run git merge --continue on my local system

Comment: Yes, obviously.